# Is there such a thing as a USB graphics card?

Tags: graphics-cards, usb, gaming

Is there a USB graphics card? I know the USB 3.0 speed would be the bottleneck, of sorts, but any additional graphics would be better than nothing.

If there isn't, is there a PCIe female to USB male conversion card to plug a graphics card in to? I can't buy a new computer, and it needs to be USB - I don't have any PCIe slots to use.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a thunderbolt connector?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There technically is. It uses the Thunderbolt standard which runs off the USB-C cable. They are typically called eGPU's and can ship with a GPU in it, but are often just the enclosure. Below are some examples.

The user Salocor, who replied to the post first, also makes a good point with a NVME M.2 to PCI-E converter being an option. Due to those not intended for often removal and are fragile, they aren't exactly a solution if you want to take your laptop on the go often. A Thunderbolt 3 eGPU enclosure like those listed below are a better option if you care about portability.

- EDIT: I just now realized you don't have a Thunderbolt connector on your laptop, so I would look into the NVME M.2 to PCI-E connector. Due to the worldwide microchip shortage, it may be easier and cheaper to buy a gaming desktop with a GPU in it.

[Razer eGPU Enclosure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D4NBPBC)
[Cooler Master eGPU Encosure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08T63FV2C)
[ASUS ROG eGPU Enclosure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06WGRT5GS)
[Dell/Alienware eGPU Enclosure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PCJXN0I)

Comment: Thanks. I found something that worked (LattePanda Alpha 864). Sheesh, those are expensive just for the enclosures.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such think as a USB 3.0 to PCIe, which is how you would connect a GPU.  However, if you are the thinking type, you could always try an m.2 to PCIe converter.  I haven't tried this before, so you'll have to do research to make sure your computer is compatible with this.  You may also have to replace your SSD.